# So... what happened to the Great Zapfish?

Tags: splatoon-3

I was just reminded... the story of *Splatoon 3* starts with the Great Zapfish being kindnapped. Again.

[image: Screenshot from Splatoon 3. We see two creatures, Shiver en Frye, presenting the news. A whale-like creature is shown on a TV screen. Shiver: "Oh, you got something, Big Man? Let's hear it!" Frye: "Uh, this was MY story to break. The Great Zapfish is gone!"]

But then the story never touches on that again. Contrary to Splatoon 1 and 2, you never save the Great Zapfish in the campaign.

So... is there any clue what happened with the Great Zapfish in Splatoon 3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You find the Great Zapfish near the end of the campaign. During the 4th section of the Rocket Battle, (The Spirit Lifter: Steerage), you find the Great Zapfish inside a large container below the rocket.

> Agent 1: AAAH! The Great Zapfish is in that huge container!
>
> Agent 2: So this is where it's been. We need to bring it back! But y'know...later, or something.

[image: Finding the zapfish]
<sub>Image from [BeardBear's Splatoon 3 walkthrough (5:53:09)](https://youtu.be/fxPRcMb1VW8?t=21184)</sub>

It's implied that Mr. Grizz kidnapped the Great Zapfish to power his rocket. After you defeat Mr. Grizz, the Great Zapfish is returned to Splatsville and can be seen on the Battle Lobby Tower.

Comment: Guess thats why I missed it. Its basically just said in 1 quick line during the last level.

Answer (score 6):

In Splatoon 3, the Great Zapfish is stolen by

> Mr. Grizz and used as a source of power for his rocket, which he planned to use with the intent of covering the planet in Fuzzy Ooze. It is located in the steerage section.

Following his defeat at the hands of Agent 3, the Great Zapfish returns to Splatsville, resting on the Unnamed Battle Lobby Tower.

According to [Inkpedia](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Great_Zapfish).